# Entries with different styling

Tags: templating, entries

Is it possible to build categories with a list of entries that have different styling, like

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    Row 1 - Entry 1 - full-wide
    Row 2 - 3 entries with (1/3 width of each)
    Row 3 - 2 entries (1/3 and 2/3 width)
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how dynamic you need this to be. One way would be to set an order of classes to loop through with [Tiwg's Cycle function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html). This would go through each class in the array, in a cycle.

```
{% set classes = ['full-wide', 'third-wide', 'third-wide', 'third-wide', 'half-wide', 'half-wide'] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <div class="{{ cycle(classes, loop.index0) }}">
        {# output entry #}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you need a bit more flexibility you could use conditionals querying the [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) to determine where you are in the output.

Comment: Thank you, I know about cycles, but in my case loops have very different div structure and adding just one class to div is not enough

Comment: Ok, if you add more specifics to your question I might be able to help. What the HTML need to look like, how variable is the entry data etc. I’m also not sure what you mean by “build categories”.

Comment: BTW, I solved my issue thanks to twig slice option

Comment: @ArturPotosyan post it as answer, that way others can use it. :)

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html